# What is the file path of env.properties file in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, properties-file, jenkins-cli

In job A , I am writing a value to env.properties file like below:
echo name=$name > env.properties

Is it possible to access that name in job B from the env.properties file?  If yes, can you please help , how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In job A, env.properties file locates in job A's workspace.

In job B, to access env.properties file in job A's workspace, you will use this path: **..\job A\env.properties**

You can use **Inject environment variable** plugin to import that name in job B from the env.properties files

[image: Inject environment variable]

**Note:**

- You can only use this way if both job A and job B running on same node